# Cargar diferentes textos en un mismo TextView (SharedPreferences)

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

Tengo dos `EditText` y lo que escribo lo guardo en `SharedPreferences` y lo cargo en un `TextView` pero solamente puedo cargar el texto de un `EditText` y no ambos textos. Lo que quiero es cargar los dos textos en un mismo `TextView`.

Por ejemplo si escribo en el primer `EditText` *Hola,* y en el segundo *Qué tal* en mi `TextView` se cargue así: **Hola,Qué tal**.

Mi código es este:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText uno, dos;
    TextView receptor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        uno = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.uno);
        dos = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dos);
        receptor = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.receptor);

        final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        // guardo los textos en sharedpreferences

        uno.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                      int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                          int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                prefs.edit().putString("uno", s.toString()).commit();
            }
        });

        dos.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                      int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                          int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                prefs.edit().putString("dos", s.toString()).commit();
            }
        });


        // cargo los textos guardados en SharedPreferences

        receptor.setText(prefs.getString("uno", "" + "dos"));

    }

}
```

Como podéis ver en mi código he probado con `receptor.setText(prefs.getString("uno", "" + "dos"));` pero en mi `TextView` siempre recibo lo que he escrito en `uno`.

¿Es posible realizar lo que pido? Gracias!

Comment: Deseas cargar los 2 valores de las preferencias, los nombres de las preferencias son "uno" y "dos", es así?

Comment: Así es @Jorgesys

Comment: revisa mi respuesta, para que entiendas por que esta solo cargandose la preferencia guardada como "uno".  receptor.setText(prefs.getString("uno", "") + prefs.getString("dos", ""));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recuerda el método [**getString()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getString(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) de las preferencias:

> **[getString(key, DefValue)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getString(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))**
>
> - **Key**: String con el nombre de la preferencia que se va a recuperar.
> - **DefValue** : String con valor a devolver si esta preferencia no existe (valor default).

---

Lo que estas realizando es que te entregue el valor de la preferencia con nombre "uno" y si no existe se escribe el texto "dos":

```
  receptor.setText(prefs.getString("uno", "" + "dos"));
```

Para obtener el valor de ambas preferencias  debería ser de esta forma, como ejemplo definiendo en ambas un valor default de "", esto tu lo decides:

```
String valor1 = prefs.getString("uno", ""); 
String valor2 = prefs.getString("dos", "");
```

por lo tanto para agregar el valor de ambas preferencias a tu `TextView`, esta sería la forma correcta:

```
receptor.setText(prefs.getString("uno", "") + prefs.getString("dos", ""));
```

Comment: Perfecto! Muchas gracias por la explicación! Ya se cuál era mi error :D, marco como solucionado! @Jorgesys